# How can i make the download of emails from GMAIL faster using IMAP and JavaMail?

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

How can I make the download of emails from GMAIL faster, using IMAP and JavaMail?
Can I do bulk download using IMAP?
I am saving the emails into MongoDB as well.
I saw some websites are doing it very quickly.

### Are there any performance tips that I can use here.

### -----------------------------------------------------

---

```
        // Get inbox folder
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
        // SET readonly format (*You can set read and write)
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // Display email Details

        // Inbox email count
        int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println("Total Messages in INBOX:- " + messageCount);

        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(1, messageCount);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Fetch only necessary headers for each message
        FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
        profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS);
        profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
        if (inbox instanceof UIDFolder) {
            profile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
        }
        inbox.fetch(messages, profile);

        System.out
                .println("Time elapsed while fetching message headers;" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

        ArrayList<Email> al = new ArrayList<Email>();
        for (int i = 1; i < messageCount; i++) {
            //System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
            Email email = new Email();
            email.setId(i + "");
            email.setSenderAddress(extractEmail(messages[i].getFrom()[0].toString()));
            email.setReceivedDate(messages[i].getReceivedDate());
            email.setSentDate(messages[i].getSentDate());
            email.setSubject(messages[i].getSubject());
            email.setMessageContent(messages[i].getContent().toString());

            email.setReceiverAddresses(new String[messages[i].getAllRecipients().length]);
            for (int j = 0; j < messages[i].getAllRecipients().length; j++)
                email.getReceiverAddresses()[j] = extractEmail(
                        messages[i].getAllRecipients()[j].toString());

            al.add(email);
            if (i % 2000 == 0) {
                emailMongoRepository.save(al);
                System.out.println("----------Bulk Save--------------------------------------------------");
                al = new ArrayList<Email>();
            }
        }

        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();

        System.out.println("Time elapsed while fetching message headers;" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried?  How is your application using the contents of the messages?  Did you see the Folder.fetch method?

Comment: Bill Thanks for the reply. We need to download the full contents of the email. For about 1000 emails roughly it takes 10 mins. I saw some sites like Zoho who are doing it quickly. I thought there might be some performance tuning I could do to make the download faster.

Comment: Assuming you have lots of memory, you can try [IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.html#MESSAGE) to prefetch the entire message.